# Post Man Custom PHP Json API Response

Tags: php, json, postman

I am using postman to check my JSON API response from web applicaton to Mobile devices.

Here is my php code.

```
$checkout = new JsonSynchronization();
$checkout -> customer_id = isset($_POST['customer']) ? $_POST['customer'] : 0;
$checkout -> store_id = isset($_POST['store']) ? $_POST['store'] : 0;

$data ['customer_id']   = $checkout -> customer_id;
$data ['store_id']  = $checkout -> store_id;
echo json_encode($data);
```

[image]

I cant get the response as expected. What is the error?... can you please assist me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing parameter in wrong place, Your parameter should go in Body tab. There your parameter will be as a post parameter, the place where you are currently sending is concatenation in URL, which is GET.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the data along in the URL, so PHP sets the $_GET global, rather than the $_POST. So replace all your $_POST with $_GET.
Or if you definitely want to use a POST, then make sure you enter the data as `form-data` when you select the POST method in postman. Currently you've got them entered as URL params.

Comment: but. how to send the values as post through POSTMan ?

Comment: i selected the method as POST And added params customer and store. Selected Form data in from under body tab. still no response. but I  getting response fine while make php code as $_GET

Comment: I have a different version of Postman, so it all looks a little bit different on my side, but I would remove the parameters from the URL completely, and also make sure that where you enter your form-data it says `Key` and `Value` rather than `URL Paramater Key` and `Value` (like I see it says in the image you attached.)